# Execution of default: in switch-case selection statements in C++

Tags: c++

My code :-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int b=10;
    switch(b)
    {
    case 40:
        cout<<"no";
    default:
        cout<<"yes";
    case 10:
        cout<<"done";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was just experimenting with my code and tried this scenario. I had expected the output to be :-

> yesdone

but the output was :-

> done

According to me, since the compiler didn't know about the `case 10:` when it was reading the `default:` statement, it must also execute the stuff inside it.

My question :-

i)  When is the `default:` case executed by the compiler and hence why is the output coming out to be

> done

rather than

> yesdone

Thanks for helping.

P.S :- I am using Code::Blocks with GCC compiler.

Comment: "According to what I know is that default case acts like the else in if-else selection statements. " no, it doesn't. The position of a `default` in a switch is not significant, any more than it is for any of the other cases.

Comment: " since the compiler didn't know about the `case 10:` " oh it definitely knows.

Comment: I don't see how that's a duplicate.

Comment: It is not the case that the compiler reads your code only once and interprets everything on a single pass. From [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch): "If condition evaluates to the value that is equal to the value of one of constant_expressions, then control is transferred to the statement that is labeled with that constant_expression."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program jumps to the first matching `case`.

Only if none is found is the `default` jumped to instead.

> `[C++14: 6.4.2/5]:` When the `switch` statement is executed, its condition is evaluated and compared with each case constant. **If one of the case constants is equal to the value of the condition, control is passed to the statement following the matched case label.** If no case constant matches the condition, and if there is a `default` label, control passes to the statement labeled by the default label. If no case matches and if there is no `default` then none of the statements in the switch is executed.

Whenever you find yourself thinking of `switch` as "a kind of `if` statement", immediately stop.

> According to me, since the compiler didn't know about the `case 10:` when it was reading the `default:` statement, it must also execute the stuff inside it.

That is just not how C++ works; it is (somewhat) smarter than that.

Comment: " _it is (somewhat) smarter than that_ " HURR DURR This looks like a function to me instead of a constructor call.

Comment: @RickAstley: 

Comment: @RickAstley: Remember, it is impossible to spell a "constructor call" in C++. When you think you have, you haven't.